# Where to find free html templates to support multiple resolutions/browsers?

Tags: html, css, templates

Is there a website where I can download free css/html templates for a website to support multiple browsers and resolutions?

(I want to make sure I can make use of client's entire screen and not show my website in the middle with "spares" on the sides)

Comment: Define "multiple browsers"? Do you want to also support legacy browsers like IE5?

Comment: @Faruz: No, just popular browsers, IE6 and above I guess.

Comment: Did you try searching the internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple googling will bring you this:

http://www.freecsstemplates.org/

Tried it once, was easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started http://csstinderbox.raykonline.com/ the technique is commonly known as fluid layouts.

Answer (score 1):

I've always preferred using Andreas Viklund's stuff.  It's easy to tweak and some of his stuff is purposed just for being widely compatible.  http://andreasviklund.com/templates/#all/1/list